# How do I convert an object from an external collection of items to an Integer type

Tags: vb.net, object

How do I convert object data type to an integer?

I am trying to do a calculation on my application, reading the OPC item’s value. Objects are used to identify the OPC items within a server.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Itemvalues(0) * 1000 + itemvalues(1)

Itemvalues is the OPC item’s value.

Itemvalues is an object data type and it can contain any data type. But you have to convert it.

(*) is multiplication.

1000 is an integer

(+) is addition

Below is the code I tried:

```
    Dim y As Object
    Dim yR As Integer
    Dim z As Object
    Dim zR As Integer
    Dim x = 1000

    yR = CInt(y)
    zR = CInt(z)

     y = itemValues(1).Value
     z = itemValues(2).Value 
    itemValues(1).Value = yR * x + zR
```

But it is displaying 0:

Which is the wrong calculation, and it is because the default value of Object is Nothing (a null reference).. How do I calculate this?

Comment: If you are calculating *anything* why use `Object` at all?

Comment: why are you using Object to calculate?

Comment: @ Plutonix, I am trying to calculate a tag that is reading the object. As an object, it can contain any data type. The value is generally the same type as requested by the corresponding ItemIdentifier. And If no type was specified, the value will be provided in its canonical form, which is null

Comment: I believe the question should be, how do I calculate the object contain data type or convert that object data to an integer? Does this make sense?

Comment: You are getting 0 becuase the calculation in your example is `yR * x + zR` => `0 * 1000 + 0 = 0`

Comment: @ Alex B. that make sense! So, how do I fix this?

Comment: How do I calculate y * x + z, with out the error message "Operands of type object used for operator '*' runtime errors could occur?

Comment: You never assign any value to y and z. So `yR = CInt(y)` => `yR = CInt(0)` => `yR = 0`. I just don´t get what you are trying to do. Can you give us the bigger scope of your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but there is an obvious logic problem in your code.

You are assigning the values of yR and zR from the variables y and z before you are assigning anything to y and z.  So these values will always be 0.

Swap the assignment order like this:

```
 y = itemValues(1).Value
 z = itemValues(2).Value 

yR = CInt(y)
zR = CInt(z)
```

There are other issues in your code but this is probably your immediate problem.